# How to Generate random code with 4 digit string and 4 digit number in Python?

Tags: python, random

I have this code

```
import random


FullChar = 'CDHKPQRVXY123456789'
total = 10
count = 8

for i in range(total):
    unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count))
    print(unique_code)
```

how can i generate random code with just 4 digit string and 4 digit number in Python?

```
Expected Output:

FH98UK67
23YTP7H4
14XG3QD2
H12P56KV
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break the tokens into characters and numbers, select four from each and then shuffle:

```
import random

chars = 'CDHKPQRVXY'
nums =  '123456789'
total = 10

for i in range(total):
    selects = random.sample(chars, 4) + random.sample(nums, 4)
    random.shuffle(selects)
    unique_code = ''.join(selects)
    print(unique_code)
```

Prints:

```
51DH63KR
P8Q749HX
P684HYQ7
Y74XDR95
358PD4HQ
8CRQ5D93
2X3R5K6Y
R48PDY23
7VXY86P2
96KQHV71
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, i'm still new in python, it's work